# Conditional statements depending on successful compilation within a Makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, compilation, conditional-compilation

For a makefile, I am trying to make it run a block of code in case of successful compilation, or an else block otherwise.

**I have tried something like this**

```
default:
ifeq ($(gcc -obuild main.c), 0)
    echo "successful"
else
    echo "you fail lol"
endif
```

But I cannot get the compilation command to be evaluated as my code suggests that I want. I thought that it could work like Bash but it seems that not, or I am missing something I dont know.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Don't you want <code>ifeq</code> rather than <code>ifdef</code>?

Comment: You are right, my mistake when writing the answer, in my Makefile I am using an **ifeq** actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with the shell, not with Make:

```
default:
    if gcc -obuild main.c  ; then \                                        
echo "sucessful" ; \
else echo "you fail" ; fi
```

Note that only the first line of the commands (`if...`) starts with a tab.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, in the “You fail”, there is a missing “lol” which is mandatory for my code.

Comment: @Mario, I am a member of the narrow age demographic that can't bear to write FORTRAN *or* lolspeak, so go ahead and downvote me and to hell with you.

Comment: don’t worry, I understand and I am not that bad. I tried your code and guess what WTF LOL it worked perfectly OMFG so I will use it, thank you very much. LMAO ROFL

Comment: @Mario *My eyes! Ahh, my eyes!*